# How to handle pdf files from server response?

Tags: react-native

I am working on React-Native mobile app and I need to handle pdf file coming from the server. The idea is when the user clicks on button, a request to the server is made and a pdf file is returned. My question is how to download and parse this file and show it to the user?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in app BUT you are going to have a lot of pain, especially with android devices.

My advice is using the Linking api and open a webbrowser:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking

The idea is to check if your `url` contains a `.pdf`. You can use a mix of:

1. https://lodash.com/docs/#includes
2. https://lodash.com/docs/#filter
3. https://lodash.com/docs/#split

When you are sure that your `url` is a pdf, you can use:

```
Linking.openURL(url);
```

Comment: The server does not return me a url containing .pdf extension. In the response I have headers: 
Content-Type: application/pdf. 
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.pdf"